# Keeping user logged in (Retrying HTTP request)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, afnetworking-2

So basically what I want to achieve is to keep user always logged in and don't bother him with manual filling of the username and password. Of course, it's necessary to login at the first time but then I store credentials in Keychain and when it's needed (e.g. token given from the server expires) I want to take those credentials automatically, relogin user and retry last request so the user get a great experience.

There is this pretty sleek soulution to this problem on [**NSScreencast**](http://www.nsscreencast.com/episodes/42-retrying-http-requests). And it'd fit my needs but... I want to use `AFHTTPSessionManager` instead of `AFHTTPRequestOperation`. If you'd ever worked with **AFNetworking 2** `AFHTTPSessionManager` methods returns `NSURLSessionDataTask` in `success:` and `failure:` blocks when `AFHTTPRequestOperation` returns `AFHTTPRequestOperation` so it's easy to reuse it.

---

**My workflow looks like this:**

I'm sending a request to the server and I get the response which I handle propely... When request succeds I get the `responseObject` and do whatever I want with it but when I get the error I check if it's 401 and if it is I want to call a `retryLogin` method (**important! This method can be executed only once**) to which I must pass the request. Inside this method I check if I have credentials stored in Keychain and If yes I call the authorization method to which I pass this request and if authorization fails I show the LoginViewController's view to the user to enter new credentials.

---

It looks like a piece of cake but the problem is **how to call `retryLogin` only once and more importantly - how to get the request from the `NSURLSessionDataTask`?** I want this app to use the iOS 7 approach so it is `NSURLSession` just in case the old approach gets deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I have impression that your problem comes from current solution architecture, so I would suggest changing it.

In workflow you described, there is serious security issue: app is going to store user credentials on device. This falls under M5 in top ten mobile OWASP (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Mobile_Top_10_2014-M5). Even though this data is stored in Keychain, still can't be considered secure according to OWASP Top 10 M1 (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Mobile_Top_10_2014-M2).

For user authentication, I'd recommend not to store user credentials at all: on LoginViewController, exchange user+password pair for OAuth2 access token, which is unique for device, and can be invalidated at any time on server side. In that case user should be redirected to login screen, without repeating request problem.

Comment: I know that there are some security issues but... This is because of a poor API design. But I really appreciate your contribution. It's one vote to convince my server developers to implement OAuth2!

Comment: If you really need to, I would abstract information needed to make a second login request to some object and use it to build new request and execute.